# Many errors "Not exist in namespace"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to c#,visula studio and kinect development. I'm trying to reconstruct the microsoft example "Interaction Gallery" ,included in the kinect sdk 1.8. I have import all the xaml and the classes that need to run the project into a new project, but maybe i have miss something... I receive many "not found in namespace" error, an example is in this code :

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.InteractionGallery.Converters">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
               <converters:NegationConverter x:Key="NegationConverter" />
                <converters:InvertibleBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InvertibleBooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
                <converters:MultiplicationConverter x:Key="MultiplicationConverter" />
                <converters:InvertibleBooleanToPromptStateConverter x:Key="InvertibleBooleanToPromptStateConverter" />
                <ExponentialEase x:Key="ExponentialEasingFunction" EasingMode="EaseInOut" Exponent="2.0"/>
                <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BackgroundGradientBrush" StartPoint="0, 0.5" EndPoint="1, 0.5">
                    <GradientStop Color="#E6E6E6" Offset="0.0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#E6E6E6" Offset="1.0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="KinectPurpleBrush" Color="#FF511C74"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ViewDataTemplate.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls/KinectButtonStyles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls/PromptControlStyles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls/TransitioningContentControlStyle.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls/VideoPlayerStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I receive the error in those lines:

```
 <converters:NegationConverter x:Key="NegationConverter" />
            <converters:InvertibleBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InvertibleBooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
            <converters:MultiplicationConverter x:Key="MultiplicationConverter" />
            <converters:InvertibleBooleanToPromptStateConverter x:Key="InvertibleBooleanToPromptStateConverter" />
```

The error is:

> Name "NegationConverter" not found in namespace "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.InteractionGallery.Converters"

There's a strange thing...when i write this piece of code, converters:NegationConverter is suggested by the autocomplete function of VisualStudio. What does it means? What i can check to find what's wrong? The way i have used to import the interactionGallery parts to my project is:
VisualStudio solutionExplorer->Add Existing item (i have repeat this step for each resource that i had need to import)

EDIT

No progress with this trouble, i had rewirite all my code, i have tried to export to new project each file,each class of the InteractionGallery sample. It must work, maybe there's some settings that i have left, the framework target is the same , and properties tab seems to be identical. However i receive the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's because the Platform target (in the project Properties, under Build) isn't set well. Try to change it to any CPU.

Helped for me several times.